# WebView не сохраняет предыдущее положение на странице

Tags: android, webview

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Когда я в WebView перехожу с 1й страницы на другую, а потом кнопкой "назад" возвращаюсь, 1я страница загружается с самого начала.

Это мелочная проблема, но если я через WebView пролистал фотогалерею, перешёл на фото и вернулся снова в фотогалерею, это становится очень неудобно, надо снова мотать с самого начала до того места, где я остановился.

**Есть ли какая-то настройка к WebView, дабы он сохранял последнее положение на предыдущей странице?**

Этой строкой пытался подгружаться с приоритетом из кэша, не сработало..

`webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);`

Сам код:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foto, container, false);
    webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      // вкл яваскрипта
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);     // встроенные кнопки вебвью
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK); //приоритет загрузки сначала с кэша

    if (isOnline()) {  //если метод проверил смартфон на соединение с интернетом, выполним загрузку
        webView.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/page/mediaset.php?id=809332342448482&album=pb.809332342448482.-2207520000.1459176546.&refid=17&ref=page_internal");

        // метод для перехода назад постранично, т.к. webView во фрагменте(фрагментов много, активити один)
        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Нет соединения", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);//если метод проверил смартфон на отрицательное соединение с интернетом

    return v;
}
```

UPD: Извиняюсь, вот ещё метод, который я использую

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте сохранять состояние `WebView` в `Bundle`.

В onCreateView() добавьте следующие строки:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
   webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);    
else
   webview.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/page/mediaset.php?id=809332342448482&album=pb.809332342448482.-2207520000.1459176546.&refid=17&ref=page_internal")
```

И переопределите `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

И `onViewStateRestored()`:

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Не сработало.. А если с Вашим кодом, какие-то из моих строк оказались лишними, я даже не знаю, что с чем может конфликтовать и что можно убрать

Comment: @zayn1991 да тут в принципе особо и не где конфликтовать...ну а что, вообще поведение никак не изменилось?

Comment: при возврате на предыдущую страницу, страница на 5-10 строк всё-таки ниже, чем была без Ваших методов, но это почти не заметно

Comment: щас точно уже не скажу, но вам надо хранить именно webview.getScollY().  И когда webview загружает страничку вызывать webView.ScrollTo(y), где Y это то самое сохраненное значение

Comment: @ermak0ff всё, я разобрался, так как я использую ссылку фейсбука, а у  них постраничная загрузка фотографий в моей ссылке, поэтому положение не могло запомниться и поэтому Ваш метод у меня работал не корректно. На других страницах Ваш метод работает. Это уже особенности фейсбука, так что выберу этот ответ, так как для обычных страниц он рабочий

Comment: @zayn1991 попробуйте так же решение которое предложил **Андроид Андроид**

Comment: @АндроидАндроид не помогло, также работает, как в этом ответе